# How to insert variable (@id) in table as auto increment in SQL server query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I want to insert @id value into Items table as auto increment.

Table Name= Items
Columns= Code, Name.

The column Code does not allow null value and is unique but it has no auto increment,
I tried to write query which will fill value (1,2,3,4,...) in column of Code as auto increment but it does not work

This is my query

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = (select MAX(Code) from Items)

SET @id =@id+1

insert into Items (Code,Name) values(@id,'m')
```

This is the error

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Code', table 'Items'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

I want @id to be inserted in column of Code as auto increment.

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: what database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Can I assume your table is empty?

In this case,

```
SET @id = (select MAX(Code) from Items)
```

is NULL,

so

```
SET @id =@id+1
```

is also null.

The correct code would be:

```
SET @id = (select ISNULL(MAX(Code),0) from Items)
```

which will return numeric 0 when there are no rows.

Typical beginner SQL error - be aware of the "poisonous" nature of NULL in SQL, which turns everything it touches into - NULL.

Comment: There is a risk MAX(Code) / @id changes between the select and the insert

Comment: Yes and no. This question is not about locking. There are a TON of scenarios where this is not a problem - from code that runs under serializable locking to code the runs in single threaded ETL processes. I answered the question asked, assuming the OP knows the site rules (provide minimal example code to replicate, IGNORING ALL OTHER ELEMENTS).

Comment: And there are *tons* of scenarios where it is a problem.  OP has a score of 8 with a basic question and you assume they understand site rules and locking?

Answer (score 0):

If you use @id you risk it changed between the two statements

Since below is one statement you don't need to wrap it in a transaction

```
insert into Items (Code, Name) 
select MAX(Code) + 1, 'm'
  from items
```

And I think this deals with empty items

```
insert into Items (Code, Name) 
select isnull(MAX(Code), 0) + 1, 'm'
  from items
```